# Composition of tempered distribution with Schwartz function

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $h\in S(R^{n+1})$ and $f\in S^\prime(R)$. Is it true that the map $R^n\ni(s_1,...,s_n)\mapsto f(h(\cdot,s_1,...,s_n)) $ is in $S(R^n) $?

I think it is true (for example, if $h $ has separated variables). But, how to prove it in general?

Comment: When $\|(s_1,\ldots,s_n)\|\to \infty$, $h(.,s_1,\ldots,s_n) \to 0$ in the $S(R)$ topology so $f(h(.,s_1,\ldots,s_n)) \to 0$. Then do the same with $s_{1:n}^\beta D_{1:n}^\alpha
 h(.,s_1,\ldots,s_n)) \to 0$ in $S(R)$

Comment: Why does $h(.,s_1,...,s_n) $ go to 0?

Comment: Try with $n=1$, $h$ is Schwartz implies $\sup_{x,y} |D_x^d x^a (1+|y|^b) h(x,y)|$ is bounded so $\sup_x |D_x^d x^a  h(x,y)| \le C_b (1+|y|^b)^{-1}$